# How to find the tail of cdf for the distribution?

Tags: poisson-distribution, binomial-distribution, cumulative-distribution-functions

I don't know how to derive the tail of cdf for this situation:

We do a Bernoulli experiment every $\frac{1}{n}$ seconds, the probability of success is $\frac{\lambda}{n}$. $Y_n$ is the waiting time for the first success, in seconds. Determine the tail of cdf of $Y_n$.

**My approach** I started by thinking of the distribution of $Y_n$ and came up that it is a geomterical distribution, something of the kind
$$P(Y_n = k) = p(1-p)^{k-1},$$
but don't know where to put the information that it is now only every $\frac{1}{n}$ seconds.
Then the tail od cdf would be 1 - cdf.

Comment: Can you define what you mean by distribution tail?

Comment: The tail of the cdf 1-P(Y_n < k)

Comment: @Gregory are u able to help?

Comment: I don't see how this is anything more than a minor transformation. Let $X$ be the number of events to see a success. The time elapsed before a success is $Y_n = \frac{X}{n}$. So,
$$ P(Y_n = k/n) = \frac{1}{n} p(1-p)^{k-1}, \ k = 1,2,\dots $$

Comment: @Gregory i think the k/n needs to be in the power of (1-k)...

Comment: Sorry, I was sloppy, it should be just without the factor $(1/n)$. The $k/n$ does not need to be in the power of $(1-p)$. I believe everything is consistent (you can/should check that the mean is what you would expect $\lambda^{-1}$).